# Challenge to implement find method as a function to fund substrings

Tags: python, methods, find, substring

Our professor has challenged us to modify the function below to successfully find substrings WITHOUT using the 'find' or 'In' features available in python. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this one. Looking for some inspiration and/or guidance.

```
def find(astring, achar):
"""
Find and return the index of achar in astring.
Return -1 if achar does not occur in astring.
"""
ix = 0
found = False
while ix < len(astring) and not found:
    if astring[ix] == achar:
        found = True
    else:
        ix = ix + 1
if found:
    return ix
else:
    return -1
```

Comment: Note that the original function could be written much more succinctly: https://gist.github.com/adeak/ff4bd511a2da02f8cb6ff1c54a060007

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you only had to add one extra loop:

```
def findsub(astring, substring):
    ix = 0
    l = len(substring)
    while ix <= len(astring)-l:
        match = True
        for j in range(l):
            if astring[ix+j] != substring[j]:
                match = False
                break
        if match:
            return ix
        ix += 1
    return -1

find2('mess', 'es')
>>> 2
```

Comment: Thanks Rocky - I appreciate the feedback. However I was trying to do it WITHOUT the 'in' statement. Basically I want python to measure the length of the substring I'm trying to find then step through astring starting at the beginning one block of characters (the block would be the same length as the substring I'm looking for) at a time till it finds a match then return the position of the first character of the substring within astring.